# Resizing using javascript manipulation of CSS

Tags: css

I'm running into a problem with resizing a window using javascript.

The first image shows the original layout, the second shows the window resizing to a smaller size, and the third shows the issue when you resize the screen to the original size.

[image: This is how the original image looks]

[image: This is how it resizes]

[image: This is how it resizes again]

```js
//none used
```

```css
* {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; ;
}


/* ########Elements below######## */
body {
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #22ee63;
}

header {
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 60%,rgba(255,0,0,0));
}

td {
 padding: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
 
}

/* Resized Elements */

@media (min-width: 397px) {
 header {
  height: 4.5rem;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 397px) {
 header {
  height: 8.1rem;
 }
}
/* ########Classes below######## */

.card {
 background-image: url("Images/LibraryStudy.png");
 background-position: center;
}

/* Resized Classes */

@media (min-width: 397px) {
 .card {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Aspect Ratio 16:9*/
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 397px) {
 .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18rem;
 }
}

/* ########IDs below######## */

#logo-container {
 width: 6.266rem;
}

#nav-logo {
 height: 2rem;
 width: 2rem;
 padding: 0.3125rem 0rem 0.3125rem 0.3125rem;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

#logo-container > h1 {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0.65625rem 0rem 0rem 0.65625rem;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1.125rem;
 font-weight: 100;
}

#logo-container > h1 > a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#login-form {
 padding: 0.3125rem 0.3125rem 0.3125rem 0rem;
 width: 17rem;
}

#login-frame {
 vertical-align: top;
}

#login-text {
 /*-moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-radius: .4rem;
 height: 1.1rem;*/

}

#persist-box {
 vertical-align: top;
}

#persist-text {
 font-size: 0.5rem;
 vertical-align: 0.2rem;
}

#password-recovery > a {
 font-size: 0.5rem;
 vertical-align: .2rem;
 padding-left: .2rem;
}

#first-card {
 z-index: -1;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}

/* Resized IDs */

@media (min-width: 397px) {

 #logo-container {
  margin: ;
  display: inline;
 }

 #login-form {
  clear: ;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: ;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 397px) {

 #logo-container {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
 }

 #login-form {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
 }
}
/* ########Pseudo below######## */
#password-recovery > a:link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#password-recovery > a:visited {
 color: gray;
}

#password-recovery > a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#logo-container > h1 > a:link {
 color: black;
}

#logo-container > h1 > a:visited {
 color: black;
}

#logo-container > h1 > a:hover {
 text-shadow: 0.01562rem 0.01562rem 0.0781rem #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <title>My CE Web App</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- CSS file -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MyCELanding.css">
  <!-- JS files -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='MyCE_scriptLanding.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div id="logo-container">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" id="nav-logo" data="Images/My_CE_Final_Icon.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
    <h1> 
     <a href="/" id="header">My CE</a> 
    </h1>
   </div>
   <form id="login-form">
    <table cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" tabindex="1">
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" tabindex="2">
        </td>
        <td>
         <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
          <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
         </label>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <input id="persist-box" type="checkbox" name="persist-login" value="1" tabindex="3">
         <label for="persist-box" id="persist-text">
          Keep me logged in
         </label>
        </td>
        <td id="password-recovery">
         <a href="/">Forgot your password?</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </form>
  </header>
  <section id="first-card" class="card">

  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use media queries?

Comment: What calls your responsive function?

Comment: @BurningLights edited the code above. its `$(window).ready(responsiveFn).resize(responsiveFn);`

Comment: @cameronjonesweb I wanted something that would work without needing multiple css sheets. (I'm also new to this, so I might be wrong in thinking that would be better)

Comment: @efong5 Media queries don't require multiple style sheets. They just activate different parts of your stylesheet depending on things like browser size, orientation, etc. Here's an article describing media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries.

Comment: @efong5 Some markup (i.e. HMTL) would be nice...

Comment: @zer00ne I didn't include it because I can't tell whats pushing the table downward (so that would be a lot of HTML) and its seems that the HTML is correctly connected because the first step works

Comment: @efong hard to visualize layout if markdown is not provided...at least it is for me

Comment: @zer00ne I'll make the edit! I hoped the pictures would be enough

Comment: @efong If it's that much trouble, then I could give you some advice about your jQuery. Since you're using rem units, use this style `html, body { font: 500 10px/1.4 'Arial'; }` If you this `$('html').css('font-size', '20px')` all of your lengths in rem will double. So there's potential for some resizing, that's theory I've never tested it myself.

Comment: @cameronjonesweb Added edits using media queries! Still not working... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you're using an older solution for a new problem. Can you try to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? It's an amazing framework for responsive and many common CSS/JS User interface problems.

If you can spend two or four hours reading about grid and many amazing things in bootstrap (or another css framework) you'll save years of productivity.

About current question, try this in else {}:

```
$("header").css("height","")
$("#logo-container").css("margin","");
$("#logo-container").css("display","inline");
$("#login-form").css("clear","");
$("#login-form").css("display","inline");
$("#login-form").css("float","right");
$("#login-form").css("margin","");
```

Comment: I'll look into it! I'm still curious about the current issue though, any insights?

Comment: Doesn't quite fix it. Thanks for the effort though!